# CGO I am passing a C struct with a pointer to a value to a go function,

Tags: c, go, memory-leaks, cgo

I am confused as to if I need to cleanup the memory in the following scenario?

I have a C function that creates a C struct and passes it to a Go function. The C struct contains an array of values (using pointer arithmetic). The Go function populates this array and returns. In the calling C function I copy the values out of the C struct and do not store them.

As this is created in Go is this garbage collected?

```
/*
C code
*/
int go_func(c_struct *s);

struct c_struct{
    val *values;
    size_t *values_cnt;
};

void example_call()
{
    struct c_struct s;
    go_func(&s)
    copy_values(s)
}

/*
go code
*/

func go_func(c *C.c_struct){
    var varr *C.val

    var v C.val = createValues()
    C.set_val_in_array(varr, *v, C.size_t(0))
    c.values = varr
}
```

Comment: You can't do this. Read carefully the section on [Passing Pointers](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would definitely be garbage collected in Go as the memory is being created in Go.